# Foliage edges turns white in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

[Image: look closely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CR9a.jpg)
[Image: look from far away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3qmb.png)

Hi, I'm new to UE, and I have been tried for days.
No matter what foliage I added to UE, they all seems good closely but becames white far away, and examples level have same issue. and if I follow all kinds of tutorials on udemy or youtube, the final effects always different with the vedio.
seems I missed some setting, but I have tried all toggles I can find in the UE editor.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/foliage-turn-white-at-distance/491489

Comment: Hi,@Crasher, not really, I read this before, this is a work around(change file format), But I am more likely to know the root cause, I can't re-import all file. From the tutorials I think some setting could solve this. e.g. if I open MedievalGameEnvironment, every meshes works fine.